# Python matrix input error [Name error]

Tags: python, python-2.7, matrix, input, nameerror

This is related to the problem in hackerrank  :  https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/grid-challenge/problem

While trying to read in the following matrix as input

```
ebacd
fghij
olmkn
trpqs
xywuv
```

I used this code :

```
grid = [[k for k in input().strip()]for l in range(nn)]
```

Where nn is the dimension of the square matrix

But I get the following error [Runtime Error]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "solution.py", line 9, in <module>
for k in input().strip():
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'eabcd' is not defined
```

Question : How to solve the error ,  or better yet 
 How to input the given matrix ?

Comment: you input should be quoted!

Comment: changing input (used in Python 3) -> raw_input (used in Python 2) is the solution.

Comment: yeah even that would work!